# How to convert Perl data into PDF?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, pdf

I need to covert Perl data into PDF. For that I have installed `CPAN` into my `UNIX` system, Now I need to install `PDF::API2`. So please give the `UNIX` command to install `PDF::API2`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this command,

```
sudo apt-get install libpdf-api2-perl
```

or,

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e "install PDF::API2"
```

For more **reference** check [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/pdf-api2/) page.

Comment: Thanq so much:)Its working

Comment: Or `sudo cpan -i PDF::API2`